# R: Automate exporting multiple lists of dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, split, export, purrr

I have a list of dataframes and would like to export them into spererate spreadsheets based on column value. Here is an example:

```
DF <- data.frame(Company=c('Alpha', 'Alpha', 'Alpha', 'Beta', 'Beta', 'Gamma', 'Epsilon'),
                 Location=c('NY', 'NY', 'CHI', 'LA', 'CHI','LA', 'LA' ),
                 ID=c('1234', '1234', '1234', '5678', '5678', '2468', '2468'),
                 Charge=c(25,25,51, 60,60, 15, 15))

DF2 <- data.frame(Company=c('Alpha', 'Alpha', 'Beta', 'Beta', 'Delta', 'Delta', 'Delta'),
                  Location=c('NY', 'NY', 'CHI', 'LA', 'CHI','LA', 'LA' ),
                  ID=c('1234', '1234', '1234', '5678', '4567', '4567', '4567'),
                  Charge=c(25,25,51, 60,60, 15, 15))


DF3 <- data.frame(Company=c('Alpha', 'Alpha', 'Beta', 'Delta', 'Delta','Delta','Delta'),
                  Location=c('NY', 'NY', 'CHI', 'LA', 'CHI','LA', 'LA' ),
                  ID=c('1234', '1234', '1234', '5678', '4567', '6789', '6789'),
                  Charge=c(25,25,51, 60,60, 15, 15))
```

When I split by Company using the code below, I am recieving an error because the company names aren't in each dataframe.

```
list(
  DF, DF2, DF3
) %>%
  purrr::set_names(paste("SpreadsheetA"), paste("SpreadsheetB"), paste("SpreadsheetC"), paste("SpreadsheetD")) %>% 
  purrr::map(~ split(.x, .x$Company)) %>%
  purrr::transpose() %>%
  purrr::iwalk(~writexl::write_xlsx(.x, file.path(path, paste0("results_", .y, ".xlsx"))))
```

The spreadsheets must have the same name for each exported excel document. The way I would like my end result to be is I want to automate exporting excel documents by company name even if a company does not appear in Spreadsheet A, B, C, or D. For example, I would have one excel document with just 3 spreadsheets instead of 4. I could really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: you are setting the names of four separate spreadsheets (A through D), but your list only has three dataframes....?

Comment: OH you want the names of the sheets to be "SpreadsheetA" etc?

Comment: To avoid the errors you can simply use the if-else statement `purrr::map(~ if(!is.null(.x$company)) {split(.x, .x$Company)} else {.x})`. However this will result in neglecting the dataframes which have no `Company` column. Other thing is that in `split` you should use the factor containing all the possible values, otherwise some entries will be missing (for example those with `Delta`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `write_xlsx` (as the error code states), requires either "a data frame or list of data frames". NULLs are not dataframes.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(writexl)

path <- "~/Downloads"

list(DF, DF2, DF3) %>%
  set_names(c("SpreadsheetA", "SpreadsheetB", "SpreadsheetC")) %>% # you can't give four names to three items, it just doesn't make any sense
  map(~ split(.x, .x$Company)) %>%
  transpose() %>%
  map(~ .x[!map_lgl(.x, is.null)]) %>%  # remove all NULL values
  iwalk(~writexl::write_xlsx(.x, file.path(path, paste0("results_", .y, ".xlsx"))))
```

Comment: instead of downvoting, it'd be great if you leave me a comment to lmk what you didn't like!

Comment: Hi Mark, I don't recall downvoting, and if I did, I apologize.

Comment: it's okay! it was probably just some random @CuRiousCoder

Comment: Thank you Mark! I just needed to make a few modifications but the crucial line of code was this :map(~ .x[!map_lgl(.x, is.null)]). Thank you everyone for your help!